# Reactjs: how to efficiently check if cell contents of table is too long

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

For the table of interest, the **last row** is used to specify the widths of the columns in the table (e.g. first cell of last row may have `style="width: 100px"` in its `<tr>` tag). I have no control over any of the width values. An example of such table is:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
       <th>row 1 header</th>
       <td>row 1 col 2</td>
       <td>row 1 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>row 2 header</th>
       <td>row 2 col 2</td>
       <td>row 2 col 3, lots of content...............</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td style="width: 160px">last row col 1</td>
       <td style="width: 130px">last row col 2</td>
       <td style="width: 200px">last row col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to implement is: if a cell content wraps into new line, then its HTML width must be larger than `350px` and less than `550px`.

For example:

suppose `row 2 col 3` content in the table above is `300px` long, so its content wraps into new line given the width constraint (`200px`) in the last row. In this case, `column 3` of the table should have its width extends to `300px`, the same width as the pixel length of the content.

if the pixel length of  `row 2 col 3` content is `400px` long, then width of `column 3` of the table should not be less than `350px` and its content should wrap into new line.

My current idea:

- I will wrap each of the cell contents in `<span> tag` to measure the pixel length of each cell content. Then I will check to see if any columns need to be resized in terms of their widths.

The problem with my current idea is that I may need to iterate through lots of cells in the table, is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 0):

> if the pixel length of  row 2 col 3 content is 400px long, then width of column 3 of the table should not be less than 350px and its content should wrap into new line.

If column 3 is 400px wide, wouldn't you set the width to 400px and then the content would not wrap?

> I have no control over any of the width values.

What DO you have control over? If you can write javascript that runs in the page you can use that to modify whatever widths are already there.

1. If the content wraps already because the table doesn't fit in its parent, wouldn't the `span` width be misleading and actually just be the same as the `td` widths?
2. If you do just check the `td` element width, you only have to check one row, all cells in subsequent rows in the will have the same width, because the entire column has the same width.
3. Actually, does `max-width` on the cells (or col element) not work here? If not, what behavior are you seeking that it doesn't provide? (see below code block)

Will your table have any `rowspan` cells? That would complicate things.

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td,th");
for (let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  log.innerText += getComputedStyle(tds[i]).width + "_";
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
       <th>row 1 header</th>
       <td>row 1 col 2</td>
       <td>row 1 col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>row 2 header</th>
       <td>row 2 col 2</td>
       <td>row 2 col 3, lots of content......................</td> <!-- I made this non-breakable word even longer -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td style="max-width:550px">last row col 1</td> <!-- add max-width and let the table layout algorithm sort it out -->
       <td style="max-width:550px">last row col 2 last row col 2 last row col 2</td>
       <td style="max-width:550px">last row col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id=log></div>
```

Comment: By _I have no control over any of the width values._, I meant the initial widths aren't set by me, but some other external source where the table is generated.

Comment: _If the content wraps already because the table doesn't fit in its parent, wouldn't the span width be misleading and actually just be the same as the td widths_. What I was trying to do was to create a `<span>` like how you did with `<div id=log></div>`, then use it to compute for the lengths of the cell content

Comment: _If you do just check the td element width, you only have to check one row, all cells in subsequent rows in the will have the same width, because the entire column has the same width._ By just checking any one row, we can't determine the maximum length of the content in each of the columns. Without knowing the maximum length, we can't set the widths of the columns (we don't want breaking content unless the cell width is larger than `350px`, so if the first row is `200px` and we set the width to `200px` then it's possible that other cells in the same column is longer than 200px and wraps)

Comment: _Actually, does max-width on the cells (or col element) not work here? If not, what behavior are you seeking that it doesn't provide? (see below code block)_ Max-width works for capping the maximum width, what is also required is that if any cell content wraps, the cell width **must** be larger than `350px` (i.e. if cell content initially wraps in the given table, extend the cell width so that content can fit in one line, if cell width must be larger than 350px to fit content in one line, then the width must be at least 350px and let the table layout algorithm sort out the rest)

Comment: _If column 3 is 400px wide, wouldn't you set the width to 400px and then the content would not wrap?_ If I know the `minimum width` for content to not wrap, I could just use min-width = 350px, max-width: 500px. The problem is I don't know that `minimum-width`, what I know is the current width of the cell which may or may not be larger than the `minimum-width`. To find the `minimum-width` of a column, I can scan through all cells in the column, but can we do better than this?

Comment: @TSP, *can we do better than this?* -- I think what I was trying to suggest is, first construct the table with no width properties except the ones you can't control (which I'm assuming are all <350px?). Then check the width of each cell in the first row. If a cell is >350px wide then add `min-width:350px; max-width:550px` to it.

Comment: @TSP, oh, I see more of the complication... if the pre-set widths cause a cell to wrap, you need to figure that out. What's stopping you from using script to remove those properties if they are just causing problems? Do you need to honor them some other way?

Comment: @TSP, I created http://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/hbtm85uk/3/ to play around with this... but Edge, FF, and Chrome all give different column sizes :(  What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: as far as i know, there is nothing special about the pre-set widths, it's just they are used to make the table look aesthetically nicer. Ideally, I want to support all browsers.  For jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/hbtm85uk/3, i'm using chrome to view it and col 3 should not wrap. I am just wondering if there is a better way of figuring out the `minimum width` of each column without scanning through all the cells of the table (in the worst case), as the table can get quite large.